# Por que grid layout solo me muestra un boton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qmainwindow

Estoy intentando hacer una interfaz con PyQt5. He copiado un ejemplo de internet donde se muestra como hacer un grid y añadirle widgets, pero al añadirle 3 botones solamente me muestra 1. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Éste es el código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Window, self).__init__()
       self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        bRun = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run",self)
        bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton("View",self)
        bExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Exit",self)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(bRun, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bViewResult, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bExit, 3, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.show()
if __name__=='__main__':
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   wind = Window()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y éste es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Atención a su indentacion, ¿es posible que estén todos en el mismo lugar? Intenta eliminar dos que no son "exit"

Comment: No, lo siento, elimina exit, para ver si los otros reaparecen

Comment: la indentación está bien solo que al pegar el código aquí se ha pegado mal. Ya he probado eso y si que aparecen, parece que se sobreponen uno a otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de @Marine1 es parcialmente correcta, asi que voy a completar la respuesta y explicar a detalle lo que esta sucediendo.

Si un layout no esta dentro de algun widget no funciona, y ese es el caso tuyo, nunca asignaste el grid a ningun widget.

**¿Si el layout no funciona porque se ve el boton?**

En Qt, el hijo se dibuja respecto al padre y en tu caso todos los botones tienen como padre a Window por lo que se dibujaran en la ventana principal, la posicion inicial de los botones sera (0, 0) por ello se dibujan en el topLeft.

La estructura correcta es la siguiente:

```
└── Window
    └── centralwidget
        └── grid
            ├── bRun
            ├── bViewResult
            └── bExit
```

Por otro lado no es necesario pasarle un padre a los botones ya que al establecerlo en un layout éste le pasará como padre al widget que se tiene establecido.

**No use self.setLayout(grid)**, ya que como muestra la siguiente imagen QMainWindow ya tiene un layout y lo que estarias haciendo es reemplazarlo eliminando la posibilidad de añadir el statusbar, toolbar, dockwidgets, etc. Como muestro en mi solución debes establecer ese layout al centralwidget con `grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)` o `centralwidget.setLayout(grid)`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando todo lo anterior obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Window, self).__init__()
       self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        bRun = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run")
        bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton("View")
        bExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Exit")

        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # se esta indicando que es el widget central
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        # establecemos que el grid estara dentro del centralwidget
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        # otro forma equivalente es:
        # grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        # centralwidget.setLayout(grid)
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(bRun, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bViewResult, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bExit, 3, 0)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.show()


if __name__=='__main__':
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   wind = Window()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Justo era eso, en el ejemplo que había copiado la clase que se definía era un Widget y no una MainWindow. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Yorch te recomiendo consultar la documentación, todo esta alli

Comment: Cambié mi respuesta, gracias por la aclaración. ¿Pudo haber hecho `self.addLayout(grid)` en lugar de `self.setLayout(grid)`?

Comment: @Marine1 eso es incorrecto, te lanzara un warning ya que estas sobreescribiendo el layout que tiene por defecto el QMainWindow

Answer (score 0):

Debe colocar esos widgets y diseños en el widget central de su `QMainWindow`. Aquí está la composición de `QMainWindow`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`QMainWindow` ya tiene un diseño que maneja cosas como barras de menú y barras de estado. También tiene un widget central para agregar tu propio diseño a. Como tal, si agrega la línea de código

```
centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
```

entonces su widget existente con diseño (centralWidget) se colocará en la construcción del diseño en `QMainWindow`. Todo esto fue gracia a [estas respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408878/why-are-my-pyqt-widgets-overlapping) (en Inglès) que puede ayudarle.
Sin embargo, tiene que establecer que el grid estara dentro del centralwidget:

```
grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
```

Secundo puede empezar a añadir su Widgets.

```
grid.addWidget(bRun, 1, 0)
grid.addWidget(bViewResult, 2, 0)
grid.addWidget(bExit, 3, 0)
```

Y finalmente puede muestrar su creación :

```
self.show()
```

La documentación da la razon y propone una forma ligeramente diferente:

> If the `QGridLayout` is not the top-level layout (i.e. does not manage
>   all of the widget's area and children), you must add it to its parent
>   layout when you create it, but before you do anything with it. The
>   normal way to add a layout is by calling `addLayout()` on the parent
>   layout.
>
> Once you have added your layout you can start putting widgets and other layouts into the cells of your grid layout using `addWidget()`, `addItem()`, and `addLayout()`. [doc.qt.io sobre QGridLayout Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) 26/7/2018

Comment: explicate mejor por favor, yo indico que `self.setLayout(grid)` es incorrecto ya al usar `some_widget.setLayout(some_layout)` le estas indicando que coloque el some_layout dentro del some_widget, en tu caso le estas indicando que el grid este dentro del QMainWindow, eso hara que se elimine el statusbar, toolbar, etc; en vez de solo establecerlo en el centralwidget como señala la imagen que muestras